# Mongoose: utils.populate: invalid path. Expected string. Got typeof 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

I am not a totally new populate user but now I do not know what's wrong.

Here I need to populate my `designerId` which is type of ObjectId. Take a look at my route.

```
ordersAdminRouter.route('/customorder/add')
    .post(function(req, res){
        body = req.body;
        console.log(body);
        CustomOrders.create(body, function(err, saved){
            if (err) throw err;
            Designs.findByIdAndUpdate(saved.designId, {$set: {status: 'Order Sent'}}, {new: true}).exec()
                .then(function(updated){
                    return CustomOrders.findById(saved._id).populate(saved.designId).exec();
            })
            .then(function(orders){
                res.json(orders);
            })
            .then(undefined, function(err){
                console.log(err);
            })
        });
    });
```

`saved._id` is working because when I remove the populate, it returns the document that I need without the populated document of course.

Take a look at my schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var customOrderSchema = new Schema({
    designId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'customDesigns' },
    size: { type: String },
    quantity: { type: Number },
    totalPrice: { type: Number },
    paymentMode: { type: String },
    rcpt_img: { type: String },
    refNumber: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('customOrders', customOrderSchema);
```

Here is my `customDesigns` schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var customDesignSchema = new Schema({
    item_name: { type: String },
    price: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    img_url_front: { type: String },
    img_url_back: { type: String },
    designer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' },
    color: { type: String },
    designDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    status: { type: String, default: 'For Qoutation' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('customDesigns', customDesignSchema);
```

I need to admit that I am new to promises on mongoose & express and this is my first time doing so. But using populate, i use it more than I can think of. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return CustomOrders.findById(saved._id).populate('designId').then(.. your code);
```

By the way, you dont must use `.exec()` then you want execute your query, `.then` executes query as well. You can skip `.exec()`

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate